# Haskell permutation library function - please clarify?

Tags: haskell, recursion, closures, permutation

This is the code for the `permutations` function in Haskell's `Data.List` module:

```
permutations            :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations xs0        =  xs0 : perms xs0 []
  where
    perms []     _  = []
    perms (t:ts) is = foldr interleave (perms ts (t:is)) (permutations is)
      where interleave    xs     r = let (_,zs) = interleave' id xs r in zs
            interleave' _ []     r = (ts, r)
            interleave' f (y:ys) r = let (us,zs) = interleave' (f . (y:)) ys r
                                     in  (y:us, f (t:y:us) : zs)
```

Can someone take the time to explain to me how this code works?

My confusion stems from the fact that I am highly used to writing functions that have no external dependencies (even if they are nested inside another function), especially if they are recursive. With the presence of `permutations` inside `perms` as well as `t` and `ts` inside `interleave'`, I am lost as far as the flow of the function is concerned.

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to write `permutations`. This one isn't the fastest. But it has one interesting property that the fastest version doesn't.

Comment: Namely, it works for infinite lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'll move rewrite the code in a form that's probably easier for you to
understand, with the internal function definitions moved outside the main function.  Note that I had to add some parameters to `interleave` and
`interleave'` so that they could "see" all the same variables they had
access to when they were defined within other functions.

I also added type signatures for clarity.

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations xs0 =  xs0 : perms xs0 []
```

The function `perms` takes two lists, and creates every possible
permutation of the elements in both lists -- but *not* including the original order. For example:

```
λ> perms "ab" "XY"
["aXYb","XaYb","aYXb","YaXb","baXY","abXY","aXbY","bXaY","XbaY","XabY","bYXa","YbXa","YXba","bXYa","XbYa","XYba","bYaX","YbaX","YabX","baYX","abYX","aYbX"]
```

So when we invoke it with an empty second list, as `permutations` does, it gives us all the *other* possible permutations of the input elements. All we have to do is tack on the original sequence, and we have out answer. (If you look at `permutations`, above, you'll see that's exactly what it does.)

```
λ> perms "abc" ""
["bac","cba","bca","cab","acb"]
```

Here's the definition or `perms`.

```
perms :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
perms []     _  = []
perms (t:ts) is = foldr (interleave (t:ts)) (perms ts (t:is)) (permutations is)
```

The function `interleave` takes two lists, and generates every possible
way to shuffle them together (as you would a pack of cards). It then
appends the third list onto the list of possible shuffles. For example:

```
λ> interleave "ab" "XY" ["@", "#"]
["aXYb","XaYb","@","#"]
```

Here's its definition:

```
interleave :: [t] -> [t] -> [[t]] -> [[t]]
interleave (t:ts) xs r  = let (_,zs) = interleave' (t:ts) id xs r in zs

interleave' :: [t] -> ([t] -> a) -> [t] -> [a] -> ([t], [a])
interleave' (_:ts) _ []     r = (ts, r)
interleave' (t:ts) f (y:ys) r  = let (us,zs) = interleave' (t:ts) (f . (y:)) ys r
                                     in  (y:us, f (t:y:us) : zs)
```

Comment: Thanks! If I were implementing this function and had known what I was doing, I would have probably written it like this; relying on capturing outside variables, namely on **pattern bindings** that can change or not even exist in another call is just plain confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of any recursive call as simply a call to the same function but with different parameters (hopefully, otherwise you may have an infinite loop), then try to follow the logic of a very simple example, like `permutations []`, `permutations [1]` or `permutations [1,2]`.

Look for when the inner expressions reduce to the base case, which is where no more recursion happens. For example `interleave'` has the base-case `interleave' _ []` and `perms` has `perms []     _  = []`.

Although I may get a bit lost myself trying to follow the windings of this function, I'm sure you will find that some expressions will reach the base-case and unfolding from there, you will be able to evaluate the recursive calls that led there.