# Haskell: Create unique n-tuples from a list of x elements

Tags: haskell

I have a list of x elements from which I would like to have all possible unique n-tuples.

So I basically am looking for an implementation of

```
nub . map (take n) . permutations
```

that doesn't unnecessarily create the duplicates.

For me, this looks like a function that has a good chance of being defined already somewhere.

Is this the case?

Comment: Are you sure that `nub . take n . permutations` produces the result you want (however inefficient it may be)? Either I'm misunderstanding what you want, or `nub . take n . permutations` won't do it. Could you please provide some examples of input and output you expect?

Comment: Perhaps you intended to write something like `nub . map (take n) . permutations $ "abcde"`?

Comment: yup, forgot the map, you're totally right

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import Data.List (permutations)

choose n list = concatMap permutations $ choose' list [] where
  choose' []     r = if length r == n then [r] else []
  choose' (x:xs) r | length r == n = [r]
                   | otherwise     = choose' xs (x:r) 
                                  ++ choose' xs r
```

Output:

```
*Main> choose 2 [0..5]
[[1,0],[0,1],[2,0],[0,2],[3,0],[0,3],[4,0],[0,4],[5,0],[0,5],[2,1]
,[1,2],[3,1],[1,3],[4,1],[1,4],[5,1],[1,5],[3,2],[2,3],[4,2],[2,4]
,[5,2],[2,5],[4,3],[3,4],[5,3],[3,5],[5,4],[4,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hayoo is very helpful for finding functions. With this [query](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=permute), I found the [permutation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/permutation) package, which seems it might do what you want, although I haven't examined the implementation in detail.

But it might be simpler to use one of the solutions discussed here on Stack Overflow. A [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=haskell%20permutation) turned up some relevant posts. You might look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301022/haskell-permutation-library-function-please-clarify/17302603#17302603) of the implementation of the `permutations` function in Data.List, and modify it to meet your needs.

Comment: Data.Choose.chooseList from the permutation package seems to be pretty much exactly what the questioner is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've asked for tuples, here is a solution exploiting the fact that list is an applicative functor:

```
Prelude> let list = [0..4]
Prelude> import Control.Applicative
Prelude Control.Applicative> (,) <$> list <*> list
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),...
Prelude Control.Applicative> (,,) <$> list <*> list <*> list
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(0,0,3),(0,0,4),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),...
```

However, since tuples of different arities are different types by definition, it's impossible to write a universal function which will produce results of different arities based on some `n` parameter.

Although I must note that this could be solved using some advanced type-level programming techniques by introducing a type-class and instances for type-level naturals representing the arities of tuples you wanted to support, but I'm sure this would be an overkill. Besides, utilizing type-naturals would also be redundant, since all the required information could be determined from the result type, so a simple type class and instances for all tuples you wanted to support would be enough.

Comment: I'm not sure about tuples, but you could return different sized lists based an input parameter.

Comment: @groovy Sure, but the question is about tuples.

Comment: that can be debated - the example he gave was `nub . map (take n) . permutations`

Comment: I might be able to resolve that question: You're both right - the question was about tuples. However, due to the same considerations as Nikita raised regarding the impossibility of having a universal function for the tuple case, I sticked my example to a result list. My case had a defined arity. Also, the question turned out to be academic-only in character as I found out that for my use case, eliminating the duplicates was unnecessary in the first place, so in reality, a simple comprehension did just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Math.Combinatorics.Multiset`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multiset-comb/0.2.1/doc/html/Math-Combinatorics-Multiset.html) (`cabal install multiset-comb`), which will avoid duplicates in the output list even if there are duplicates in the input list:

```
import Math.Combinatorics.Multiset  (fromList, kSubsets, permutations)

permute :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
permute n = concatMap permutations . kSubsets n . fromList

main = print $ permute 2 [1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Produces:

```
[[2,3],[3,2],[1,3],[3,1],[1,2],[2,1],[1,1]]
```